# Install push stream module for nginx

Tags: nginx, module, centos

I need to install push stream module for nignx.

```
cd /
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.7.12.tar.gz
tar -xvf nginx-1.7.12.tar.gz
cd nginx-1.7.12
git clone http://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module.git
```

next...

```
./configure --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_gzip_static_module --add-module=nginx-push-stream-module
```

after result...
    adding module in nginx-push-stream-module
    checking for http_push_stream_module ... found
    + ngx_http_push_stream_module was configured

```
make && make install
```

make - OK

run command "nginx -V"

```
 nginx version: nginx/1.7.12
built by gcc 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) (GCC) 
TLS SNI support enabled
 configure arguments: --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_spdy_module --add-module=nginx-push-stream-module
```

service nginx start

```
[root@p11 nginx-1.7.12]# systemctl status nginx.service
апр 14 03:26:02 p11.ihc.ru nginx[31057]: Starting nginx: nginx:     [emerg] unknown directive "push_stream_shared_memory_size" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:59
апр 14 03:26:02 p11.ihc.ru nginx[31057]: [FAILED]


 [root@p11 nginx-1.7.12]# nginx -V
 nginx version: nginx/1.7.12
 built by gcc 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) (GCC) 
 TLS SNI support enabled
 configure arguments: --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_spdy_module --add-module=nginx-push-stream-module
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you nginx install:

```
nginx -V
```

This command view all compile options etc.
You will can check nginx-push-stream-module module

Answer (score 0):

Your build looks good so I'd be checking that you don't have multiple nginx binaries in your $PATH that your service could be executing instead of your new build.

```
 whereis nginx
```

You've installed your new binary into /usr/local/sbin, so check you haven't forgotten to remove older nginx distributed packages that could interfere.

```
 rpm -qa | grep ^nginx
```

If all else fails, move the git repo out of your nginx source and try again:

```
 git clone https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module.git
 wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.7.12.tar.gz
 tar -xvf nginx-1.7.12.tar.gz
 cd nginx-1.7.12

 ./configure --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_gzip_static_module --add-module=../nginx-push-stream-module

 make && make install
```

Even better, if you want to automate builds this is what I use on my servers:
https://github.com/cubicdaiya/nginx-build

Hope it helps!